# How to forward a transaction from api tests to the application start?

Tags: php, yii2, transactions

I write API tests. I would like to run them in the transactions, in order to get rid of dependencies in tests. I thought if it’s possible to transfer a transaction somehow at the start of the application. If possible, tell me please the documentation or share your experience.

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: @KoalaYeung codeception

Comment: What do you mean with "transfer a transaction at the start of the application"? As far as I know, Codeception uses transactions by default for all the tests. And if you haven't disabled that, it should work by itself.

Comment: Have you tried to code your transaction in the `_before` and `_after` method? ([Reference](https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage))

Comment: Codescepton set up to use transactions, unit tests work well. There is a problem with api tests. In the test, an http request is sent by url, the yii application starts, but already without a transaction. So I thought, is it possible to somehow transfer a transaction.

Comment: Improve spelling